# Which class is used to print Thread Dump of JVM Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-languages, jvm-crash

I want to generate the thread dump of my running application. However, when I do kill -3 PID, it generate the thread dump at the console of the running application.

I want to generate it to a file. I know I can run the application as ./run.sh > thread_dump or I can also use jstack utility to redirect it to file.

However, I do not want to use any of those. In another approach I redirected the complete output of my console to a file by:

```
            File file = new File("out.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    System.setOut(ps);
```

Now every output is written in out.txt. But still, when I do kill -3 , it writes the thread dump to console.

What am I missing in the third approach? Would anybody know, what class/source is called when kill -3 is called on a JVM, so that I can look how thread dump is exactly written on making a kill -3 request/command?

Comment: The source for this is entirely in the JVM in C++.  You need to have a build of the OpenJDK, which you can modify to dump to a file instead.  BTW YOu can write your own thread dump using JMX and Thread.getAllStackTraces() etc but this won't be triggered by `kill -3`

Comment: Then, How does tomcat writes thread dump to a file by default.

Comment: I mean how does tomcat writes thread dump to catalina.out file.

Comment: Looking at catalina.sh, it runs java with output redirected to catalina.out. They use the solution you mention in your second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [jmap -dump](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html#options) option to dump heap dump of a running application. Here is an interesting blog on the oracle website describing how to Programmatically dump heap from Java applications.

https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java